# Migrations Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Está acontecendo um erro quando vou fazer a migration um para muitos.
O objetivo é fazer com que um cliente vai ter muitos telefones e um telefone vai pertencer apenas a um cliente.
No código abaixo podem observar que o cliente_id referencia o campo id da tabela clientes.

```
    Schema::create('telefones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('cliente_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('telefones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('cliente_id')->references('id')->on('clientes');
    });
}
```

Mas quando vou executar o comando `php artisan migrate` ele cria a tabela só que não tem o `foreign key` e dá o seguinte erro:

```
PS C:\projetos\appteste> php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2019_07_28_221050_cria__tabela__telefones

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' at line 1 (SQL: create table `telefones` () default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at C:\projetos\appteste\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') default character
set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' at line 1")
      C:\projetos\appteste\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:63

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' at line 1")
      C:\projetos\appteste\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:61
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não pode utilizar o `Schema::create` duas vezes para mesma tabela. Para adicionar a chave estrangeira você pode utilizar o mesmo escopo do primeiro `create` ou utilizar o `Schema::table` para fazer as alterações.

```
Schema::create('telefones', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('cliente_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('telefones', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('cliente_id')->references('id')->on('clientes');
});
```

> Você pode trocar os dois métodos `integer` e `unsigned` - que funcionam perfeitamente - para `unsignedInteger` que tem o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Erra isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Não precisa fazer 2 schema para relaciona poderia fazer o foreign abaixo do unsigned

Comment: @LucasAntonio, exatamente isso que descrevi no início da resposta. Prefiro sugerir a criação dos relacionamentos desta forma - separado - pois assim fica mais fácil a manutenção.

Comment: Não acho, eu faço junto pra agilizar bateu o olho já sabe onde ta o relacionamento assim, dessa forma ai tenho que ler um schema e depois ler outro, processos atoas e ficará mais lento a migration.